# Store changelog in openldap database

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I want to store changelog in my OpenLDAP database which contains details like this: [This is a sample entry from another system which is using openLDAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtgl1.png)

I configured audit log but they are storing less information and it is in LDIF file not directly in the OpenLDAP database.
I am new to OpenLDAP please help, I have no idea how to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was cross-posted on Stack Overflow, and I answered it there.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/61672311